# Data structure that maps unique id to an object

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I'm looking for a C++ data structure that will let me associate objects with a unique numeric value (a key), and that will re-use these keys after the corresponding object have been removed from the container. So it's basically somewhat of a hybrid map/queue structure. My current implementation is a

```
std::map<size_t, TObject>
```

and I insert objects like this:

```
 size_t key = (m_Container.end()--)->first + 1;
 m_Container[key] = some_object;
```

which works fine for my purposes (I will never allocate more than size_t objects); yet still I keep wondering is there is a more specialized container available, preferably already in the stl or boost, or that there is a way to use another container to achieve this goal.

(Of course I could, rather than taking the highest key in my map and adding one, every time go through the map and search for the first available key but that would reduce complexity from O(1) to O(n) Also it would be nice if the API was a simple

```
size_t new_key = m_Container.insert(object);
```

).

Any ideas?

Comment: This breaks when the container is empty (`end==begin`). Also, you might have missed `m_Container.back()`.

Comment: In my code I do have a check to see if the map is empty, this was just for illustration. Furthermore a std::map doesn't have a .back().

Comment: m_Container.rbegin()->first might be somewhat more readable than (m_Container.end()--)->first ...?

Comment: True. Still, with Valentin's Day coming up and all, I figured ()--)-> would fit nicely in the flower theme ;)

Comment: Note: The post decrement operator (--) decrements the lvalue expression. __BUT__ the result of the expression (returned to the expression for further processing) is the original value. Thus the operator -> used to get first is being used on end() (an invalid operation).

Comment: Correct, as I found out much to my chagrin :) It seemed to work at first because my test set didn't hit that point while I thought it did :/ So I stuck to Pukku's suggestion, and removed my ascii artish code :)

Comment: @Roel did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're never going to allocate more than `size_t` keys then I recommend you simply use a static  counter:

```
size_t assign_id()
{
    static size_t next_id;
    return next_id++;
}
```

And if you want a nice API:

```
template<class Container>
size_t insert(Container & container, TObject const & obj)
{
     container.insert(obj);
     return assign_id();
}

std::set<TObject> m_Container;
size_t new_key = insert(m_Container, object);
```

Comment: How is `object` and `new_key` associated with each other? Shouldn't the container be a `map` instead of `set`?

Comment: I thought the OP would take care of that himself (probably by storing the key inside a data member of the object).

Comment: Also, the OP seemed to be using the map just for the sake of keeping a number of the objects createad so far. That's why I proposed my function as a more lightweight way of achieving the same effect.

Comment: I need a way to keep track of the objects in an unobtrusive way, i.e. without changing the object being tracked (so without adding an ID). Even if I'd assign ID's I'd still need to find out what the latest ID is upon making a new object, merely shifting the problem. I need to keep track of the object to know which ones are still in the queue to be processed, and which ones are done.

Comment: My code solves the problem of knowing what the latest ID was. If you also need to attach an ID to each object then I suggest you use my code in combination with a `map<TObject, size_t>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you exactly want from your ID. As it happens, each object already *has* a unique ID: its address! There are no two distinct objects with the same address, and the address of an object doesn't change over its lifetime.

`std::set<T>` typically stores its T values as members of larger nodes, not independent objects. Still, the T subobjects are never moved, and thus their addresses too are stable, unique identifiers.

Comment: I need to identify objects 'by value', a copy of them is passed to a separate thread, an action is done based on the content of that object, then a message is send back to the UI saying 'object x is processed', without sending back the actual object (it's irrelevant for the notification). I need to be able to remove the object that was processed from the list of object that are still  in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Create `std::set<key_type> removed_keys;` of the removed keys. If `removed_keys` is not empty then use key from `removed_keys` else create a new key.

Comment: Or possibly not a set. It doesn't seem to matter what order the freed-up keys are re-used, in which case a stack would be a better fit (and probably more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

#### Why not just use a vector?

```
std::vector<TObject> m_Container;

size_t key = m_Container.size();
m_Container.push_back(some_object);
```

Of course this could be completely useless if you have other usage characteristics. But since you only describe insert and the need for a key (so extracting) it is hard to give any other clear answer. But from these two requirements a std::vector<> should work just fine.

If you have some other usage characteristics like: (Elements can be removed), (we insert elements in large blocks), (we insert elements infrequently) etc these would be interesting factoids that may change the recommendations people give.

You mention that you want to search for un-used elements ID's. This suggests that you may be deleting elements but I don't see any explicit requirements or usage where elements are ebing deleted.

#### Looking at your code above:

```
size_t key = (m_Container.end()--)->first + 1;
```

This is not doing what you think it is doing.
It is equivalent too:

```
size_t key = m_Container.end()->first + 1;
m_Container.end()--;
```

The **post** decrement operator modifies an lvalue. But the result of the expression is the original value. Thus you are applying the operator -> to the value returned by end(). This is (probably) undefined behavior.

See the standard:

> Section:5.2.6 Increment and decrement
> The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand.

```
m_Container.end()--  // This sub-expresiion returns m_Container.end()
```

#### Alternative:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class X
{
    public:
        T const& operator[](std::size_t index) const    {return const_cast<X&>(*this)[index];}
        T&       operator[](std::size_t index)          {return data[index];}
        void        remove(std::size_t index)           {unused.push_back(index);}

        std::size_t insert(T const& value);
    private:
        std::vector<T>                  data;
        std::vector<std::size_t>        unused;
};

template<typename T>
std::size_t X<T>::insert(T const& value)
{
    if (unused.empty())
    {
        data.push_back(value);
        return data.size() - 1;
    }
    std::size_t result  = unused.back();
    unused.pop_back();
    data[result]    = value;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Correct about the post-increment, that was a silly mistake to make.
It would certainly be possible to do this with a vector, it can be done with any type of container. I guess I phrased my question wrong. I'm not looking for 'a solution', I already have one and can think of 10 others, I was more theorizing and wondering whether this was a known pattern and is there is an optimal complexity for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you need `std::map` to not remove a *key, value* pair?

This sounds like an attempt at premature optimization.

A method is to replace the *value* part with a dummy or place holder value.  The problem in the long run is that the dummy value can be extracted from the `std::map` as long as the key exists.  You will need to add a check for dummy value every time the `std::map` is accessed.

Because you want to maintain a key without a value, you most likely will have to write your own container.  You will especially have to design code to handle the case when the client accesses the key when it has no value.

Looks like there is no performance gain for using standard containers and a key without value pair.  However, there *may* be a gain as far as memory is concerned.  Your issue would reduce fragmentation of dynamic memory; thus not having to re-allocate memory for the same key.  You'll have to decide the trade-off.

Comment: No I don't want to keep the keys but remove the objects, I want to remove the key/value pairs.